# ExpressJS is stacking up

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Im trying to make an API that works through the power of the framework `nodejs` and the node module/package `express`

I made an API that once you call `localhost:3000/?username=nameHere`

It makes some http requests using the `request` module, waits for the callback and then sends the result out as html to the person requesting `localhost:3000/?username=nameHere`

However if I refresh it quickly, the ending result would be a stack of 2 results instead of one

Example: `localhost:3000/?username=nameHere` would return 1 array
if i quickly call/refresh it 2 times, the route acts the same for everyone and the ending result would stack up 2 arrays

How do I overcome this? I'm seriously new to routing.

Here's my code, `app` is simply `express()` and i Did define some variables at the top, GetAllItems basically is a function that does a bunch of requests made by the the request module, wraps up all the data and sends it back as a callback

```
app.use('/', function(req, res,next) {
    console.log("request");
    if (req.query.username!==undefined) {
    GetID(req.query.username,function(ID){
        if(ID!==undefined || ID!=="undefined"){
            console.log("Cool");
            GetAllItems(ID,function(cb){
          res.send(JSON.stringify(cb));
                next();
            });
        }else{
            console.log("Not found");
            res.send("Not Found");
        }
    })
}else{
   res.send("No username"); 
}});
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample

Comment: Why do you call `next()`? Anyway, I think that if one response contain more than 1 array the problem is in your `GetAllItems` function. The `res.send` will only send the `cb` data once in each response

Comment: @yeya The problem is it serves (GetAllItems works fine) as like a single thread, if 2 people request the file at the same time, the ending html will be doubled

Comment: If `GetAllItems` always return single response - there will be no double in response

Comment: @yeya No, the problem isn't in GetAllItems's response, the problem is when a person loads my page 2 times quickly, GetAllItems() is called twice and the returned html is 2 arrays instead of 1, simply speaking, if you and I loaded the page at the same time, it would print out some weird duplicated array simply because it's basically the same thread